# Create a union from an enum with an appended string in TypeScript

Tags: typescript, enums, union-types

I want to add a type definitions for singular and plural versions of my enum with a translation library. The translation library looks for an appended string to the key name. i.e.

```
foo_one: "foo",
foo_other: "foos"
```

I want to define a type to match my implementation:

```
settings: {
  day_type: {
    [DayType.BusinessDay + "_one"]: "Business day",
    [DayType.BusinessDay + "_other"]: "Business days",
    [DayType.CalendarDay + "_one"]: "Business day",
    [DayType.CalendarDay + "_other"]: "Calendar days",
  },
},
```

My current definition:

```
enum DayType {
  BusinessDay = 'BUSINESS_DAY',
  CalendarDay = 'CALENDAR_DAY'
}


type SettingTranslations = {
  day_type: {
    [key in DayType | string]: string; // <- fix this
  };
};
```

Comment: Could you [edit] the code here to be a self-contained [mre] suitable for pasting into a standalone IDE? The definition of `DayType` would be helpful, in addition to anything else that avoids unrelated errors (is the definition in an `interface` or something?  If so, give the interface... as it is now it's only a fragment of something).

Comment: Perhaps [this approach](https://tsplay.dev/mp8Dbm) is what you're looking for? If so I could write up an answer explaining; if not, what am I missing?

Comment: @jcalz that is exactly what I'm after. Sorry if my question was abit vague. I don't know the nomenclature that well.

Comment: Okay I will write up an answer when I get a chance, probably not until tomorrow (it is bedtime in my time zone )

Comment: Awesome, I'd love to know why the `as const` is needed. My guess is that it doesn't recognize the string as an enum and string interpolation doesn't cast it correctly?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [template literal types](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-4-1.html#template-literal-types) both to convert enums to their corresponding string [literal types](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/everyday-types.html#literal-types) and to concatenate string literals:

```
interface SettingTranslations {
    day_type: {
        [K in `${DayType}${"_one" | "_other"}`]: string;
    };
};
```

This yields the following property for `day_type`:

```
/* (property) SettingTranslations.day_type: {
    BUSINESS_DAY_one: string;
    BUSINESS_DAY_other: string;
    CALENDAR_DAY_one: string;
    CALENDAR_DAY_other: string;
} */
```

---

Unfortunately your implementation won't type check:

```
const settings: SettingTranslations = {
    day_type: { // error! Type '{ [x: string]: string; }'
        [DayType.BusinessDay + "_one"]: "Business day",
        [DayType.BusinessDay + "_other"]: "Business days",
        [DayType.CalendarDay + "_one"]: "Business day",
        [DayType.CalendarDay + "_other"]: "Calendar days",
    }
};
```

That's because string concatenation using [the `+` operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Addition) does not perform concatenation of string literals at the *type level*; it yields only `string`.  And so the compiler sees that object as having a `string` [index signature](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/objects.html#index-signatures) `{[x: string]: string}`, which is not known to have the required keys.

This lack of literal type concatenation is intentional; see [microsoft/TypeScript#51583](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/51583), or [this comment on microsoft/TypeScript#44905](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/44905#issuecomment-875784954).  It would end up breaking too much real-world code to do this, producing [union types](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/everyday-types.html#union-types) too large to represent.

If you want to get string concatenation both at the type level and at runtime, you can use a [template literal string](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Template_literals) instead:

```
const settings: SettingTranslations = {
    day_type: { // error! Type '{ [x: string]: string; }'
        [`${DayType.BusinessDay}_one`]: "Business day",
        [`${DayType.BusinessDay}_other`]: "Business days",
        [`${DayType.CalendarDay}_one`]: "Business day",
        [`${DayType.CalendarDay}_other`]: "Calendar days",
    },
}
```

Oops, that still didn't work, you still get `string`.  By default, template literal strings *do not* have template literal types.  That behavior was actually implemented in [microsoft/TypeScript#41891](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/pull/41891), but it broke too much code (for the same reason as the problem with `+`) and was reverted at [microsoft/TypeScript#42588](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/pull/42588).

Luckily there is a way to explicitly opt in to having template literal types for template literal strings.  And that's to use a [`const` assertion](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-3-4.html#const-assertions), as implemented in [microsoft/TypeScript#40707](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/pull/40707):

```
const settings: SettingTranslations = {
    day_type: { // okay
        [`${DayType.BusinessDay}_one` as const]: "Business day",
        [`${DayType.BusinessDay}_other` as const]: "Business days",
        [`${DayType.CalendarDay}_one` as const]: "Business day",
        [`${DayType.CalendarDay}_other` as const]: "Calendar days",
    },
}
```

Now the code type checkes because the compiler can verify that each of those computed keys is of the right string literal type.

[Playground link to code](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ts=4.9.3#code/KYOwrgtgBAIghgTwCoIA7CgbwFAEgBCYAzgJYjBFHwJQC8UA5PgKoDKAkgHICirrA+jACCATQYAaPAGE4AG1AATOACdqdRlKEAZbp2EAlQaIbYAvtmxkALsGUAzOAGMMrYFatkA5kmVwQRWTgPAHt-LDwlBH4rNGAALnDcXABtAGkoMigAAwASTGoUdFM8gCJ+UOASqAAfKDLgqwALWxLTLIBdBKIrZS8AbjxTAaHsAHoAKigAClRlYPRlGIBKKFd3Lx8-AKCSUKIAOkjo2IScAjYuXgFhEXLyLp7+vBYOHj4jW4bm5QfekE8BrhNDo9EJDDc7vEoN0-gDpNpdAYPuUmrZfk9TFBxqMLBZ5FZoW4PP8iAk1sTvL5-IEQv4BhYiESvER1GcjjF0KcoKNRlBbHNlABCKCFDAMTBQZIAD3R-060Me-z6UFMJiSyQKsX2hFI5EoagA1HVISV5SUdWQKCzIiVJOrNehtcRLfrEFAjfVUcpTQlzc69dbEERbXgUg7gPsZPIQEpVG6PSazRaA1AbXaw4hRZG5IoVIbjV8Wmao7nlKmgyHcOYRthGesSayIohjpysNzefzgkKRbFGBLpbLPPKYf0VWqUrl8pmtcmrdRTJCOr7Z5RywhKxO8uGnbq54gF4XlEu6ivAwhg+nkpPtyWY3n94uk-6rWuN1et9PHbfY-OUd9jyU34qGuF6DJI5gMkyDb0GyzYclCEo8lAwQANaIKG75TsgM7Pq6CAHuQWRQHALKOHsVhPruq5phh16fhGp6-oeREkVAZH+BRy64WeoHqnR2Ffjmd5xvhi7EaR5GUS6Z5vvxWZASJB5eixEkccWQmxiBlamOBUC4kAA)